# How to perform a generalized union over a sequence of sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Let $P \subset \mathbb{N}$ be a finite index set and $S$ be a sequence of arbitrary length and arbitrarily many repeating elements from $P$.
Now, suppose there is a set $R_i$ for every $i$ in $S$, where $R_i = R_j$ if $i = j$.

How would I write the generalized union of every set $R_i$?

Is there a way to create a set G of the unique elements of $S$, so that this could work?
$$
\bigcup_{i \in G} R_i
$$

Comment: Technical point: a sequence of elements of $P$ could have repeats or could omit some elements of $P$. A sequence only represents a permutation if it contains exactly one occurrence of each element of $P$. As for your question, it depends on exactly how you formalise the definition of sequences. If you think of sequences as functions, then the set of elements of a sequence $s$ is just the range of $s$, $\mathsf{ran}(s)$. If you don't like that you could write $\{s_k \mid i \in P\}$. However, if the sequence represents a permutation of $P$ then its range is just $P$.

Comment: A sequence and a permutation are different things! Moreover, I'm not seeing how the order of your sequence matters (since unions are commutative). What would be wrong with $f : P \to 2^P$ picking out a subset of $P$, and then looking at $\bigcup_{j \in f(p)} R_j$? This has the added benefit of "typechecking", if you'll forgive my use of CS terminology

Comment: It depends on how you're representing "a sequence of elements from $P$". The name "symmetric group operator" makes it sound like a bijection $\sigma:P\to P$, but then your union expression is just $\bigcup_{j\in P}R_{f(i)(j)}$, which is equivalent to $\bigcup_{j\in P}R_j$ - it doesn't actually depend on $i$.

Comment: @RobArthan, right, what I meant was that $f(i)$ is an arbitrary sequence from $P$ of arbitrary length and arbitrarily many repeating elements, so it is not necessarily a permutation of $P$. Thanks for the answers. Which notation is more conventional?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor, right, I've edited the question to reflect that $f(i)$ can be a sequence of arbitrary length and arbitrarily many repeating elements. The order of the sequence returned by $f$ is important for an external application. However, as you point out, the order is not necessary for performing the generalized union. Despite this, I need to keep $f$ as it is defined in the question.

Comment: I've updated the question so that it only includes essential information.

Comment: Anything wrong with $G = \{ S_i : i \in \Bbb{N}\}$? (Also note you don't to worry about "uniqueness" audit is automatic that $R_i = R_j$ is $i = j$, because $R_i = R_i$.)

Comment: @RobArthan, nice! That looks like what I need. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: A pleasure. P.S. "audit" should read "as it" above - dratted autocorrect!